Как настроить postgresql в django для тестов
Я пытаюсь настроить postgresql в django через файлы .pg_service.conf и .pgpass чтобы могли работать тесты.
Я хочу чтобы по крайней мере основные настройки могли быть записаны через .pg_service.conf и .pgpass. Но при такой записи, когда я запускаю тесты, то вылазит куча ошибок (все кроме тестов работает нормально)
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'service': 'myservice',
        },
        'TEST': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'NAME': 'testdb',
            'USER': 'testuser',
            'PASSWORD': 'testpassword',
        }
    }
}

При этом при такой записи все работает
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'maindb',
        'USER': 'mainuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mainpassword',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': 'testdb',
            'USER': 'testuser',
            'PASSWORD': 'testpassword',
        }
    }
}


В общем, проблему я так и не смог решить. Теперь использую os.getenv() вместо .pg_service.conf и  .pgpass
